# Heroku deleting files upon git push?

Tags: django, git, heroku

I have a media folder that stores all my uploaded images during development and I'm pushing my django(1.5.1) project to a dev server on heroku. Inside the media folder I have

```
media/
    # cache and images were commited before .gitignored was added
    cache/ # store thumbnails
    images/ # store images
    .gitignore
```

the .gitignore has

```
*
!.gitignore
```

The problem is whenever I git push to heroku, all my testing uploads are wiped out by git.  Is there a way to deal with this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't an issue with Git, but rather with Heroku. Heroku's [file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem) is ephemeral, and is reset between deploys. Use a service like Amazon S3 to store uploaded files.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help my problem.  I don't want the new files on heroku to wiped out.  I don't care about what is in the git media folder.

Comment: @Derek: It's not git that's wiping them out—Heroku has an ephemeral file system (temporary files are deleted between deploys). Use something like S3 for permanent file storage.

Comment: @Derek mipadi is right. I'll explain how Heroku does their deploys. They create a new directory, pull from git into that new directory (this will be your new version), then when it's ready to face the world (all the work has been done setting up the application), it will just change the working directories symlink to your new release directory. This is the correct way deploys should behave. But that means any files that were uploaded and stored in your old version, will not be available to your new version. Use Amazon S3 to store your uploaded files, and keep track of them in a DB.